# "Module not found" Flow error for autogenerated file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype, es6-modules

I have three ES2015 modules: `store.js`, `middleware-config.js` and autogenerated `middleware-config-settings.js` with some logic and imports.

Module `middleware-config-settings.js` is generated from `webpack.config.js` when the app starts with `npm start`.

`store.js`:

```
// @flow
...
import middlewareConfigs from './middleware/middleware-config';
...
```

`middleware-config.js`:

```
// @flow
...
import defaultSettings from './middleware-config-settings';
...
```

Module `middleware-config-settings.js` is just simple JSON:

```
// @flow
export default {
  profilingMiddlewareConfig: {
    isActive: true,
  },
  reduxDiffStateMiddlewareConfig: {
    isActive: true,
    params: {
      ignoredActionTypes: [],
      approvedActionTypes: []
    }
  }
};
```

When I checked the project with `flow` I got error:

> ./middleware-config-settings. Required module not found

**First,** I tried ignore Flow check for the line:

```
// @flow
...
// @FlowFixMe: ignore
import defaultSettings from './middleware-config-settings';
...
```

That apporach works fine if `middleware-config-settings.js` not exists. Otherwise I got another problem: after `npm start` `middleware-config-settings.js` file created and next `flow` execution fails with another error:

> Error suppressing comment. Unused suppression

**Second,** I tried add `middleware-config.js` into `[ignore]` section in `.flowconfig`. But then I got new error message from `store.js`:

> ./middleware/middleware-config. Required module not found

After that I add `store.js` into `[ignore]` section too and `flow` executes well but I think that it's not right way.

**Third approach** is similar to second - I just removed `// @flow` from `middleware-config.js` and `flow` executes fine. And that approach also not too good (all my modules should be `flow`ed).

So I have two questions:

1. How can I get errorless `flow` execution without excluding any of that files from `flow` checks?
2. Why I got error about `store.js` when I add `middleware-config.js` into `[ignore]` section? If my understanding of the [documentation](https://flowtype.org/docs/advanced-configuration.html#ignore) is right so it's not correct behavior:

   > The [ignore] heading in a .flowconfig file tells flow to ignore files matching  the specified regular expressions when type checking your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that problem with some hack with importing `middleware-config-settings.js` with `require` and storing module's name in the variable (for avoiding `Required module not found` error) and with adding `@FlowFixMe` (for avoiding `The parameter passed to require() must be a literal string.` error):

```
let moduleName = './middleware-config-settings';
// @FlowFixMe: import autogenerated file.
let defaultSettings = (require(moduleName): any);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- Avoid autogenerating files (I assume you have already considered this and decided against it).
- Create a permanent `middleware-config-settings.js.flow` that contains a prototypical config, and check it in to version control. Then, Flow will look at that file instead of looking for the `.js` file and it will typecheck, but the actual values will be generated on each run. The main downside of this approach is to make sure that the structure of your `.js.flow` file matches the structure of the generated `.js` file when you make changes.
- Introduce an explicit build step that generates the required files, rather than including that step implicitly in your `npm start` script. Then, just make sure that you run that build step before using Flow.

Regarding your second question, I believe that if you add something to the [ignore] section, Flow just pretends it doesn't exist at all. So, if you import an ignored file from a checked file, Flow will give you an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
1. I have to generate that file. 
2. That file created only if not exists and then each user can edit it with his own values (and I'm not really want create one more fake file)
3. It's a bit harder than I want to do it.
I solve it with another approach.